# How to fetch complete node text value containing html tags using DOMParser in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, domparser

I have tried using node.getTextContent, this only gives value till before html tag.

Eg:

XMl File:

```
<node1>abcd<br/></node1>
```

`System.out.println(node.getTextContent)` : This prints "abcd".

Expected Output: `"abcd<br/>"`

Here, "br" is also considered as Element Node by DOMParser. DOMParser is not returning 9 for its ("br") node type value.

How to achieve the expected output using DOMParser in Java?

Comment: Since you are using .getTextContent, it would always give you only the text content. If you need other nodes as well, you should use node.getChildNodes() and then loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

<br/> is considered an element node because it is an element node. You can convert it in your output in any way you like, eg:

```
if(node.nodeName=='br'){
  out = "\n"
}
```

or, you could transform it using XSL.

Comment: yeah, but if there are many such html tags then those tags need to be hardcoded exclusively.